# Kaleidoscope tutorial cannot find header `ExecutorProcessControl.h`

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

To follow [Kaleidoscope tutorial part 4](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl04.html), I downloaded the header file [KaleidoscopeJIT.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llvm/llvm-project/main/llvm/examples/Kaleidoscope/include/KaleidoscopeJIT.h). But once I include it, I get the following error

```sh
$ clang++ -g main.cpp kaleidoscope.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core orcjit native` -O3 -o kaleidoscope
In file included from kaleidoscope.cpp:18:
././include/KaleidoscopeJIT.h:21:10: fatal error: 'llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/ExecutorProcessControl.h' file not found
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/ExecutorProcessControl.h"
```

The closest information to it I could find at [documentation page](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1orc_1_1ExecutorProcessControl.html), but there is no information on how to successfully compile it. Any suggestions on how to resolve header dependency?

Here are my config options,

```sh
$ llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core orcjit native
-I/usr/lib/llvm-10/include -std=c++14   -fno-exceptions -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-L/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib 
-lLLVM-10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you pull the correct files. You are using llvm-10 so you need to use the kaleidoscope tutorial from that [version](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/llvmorg-10.0.1/llvm/examples/Kaleidoscope).

Comment: Nice, was able to compile using llvm-10's header file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llvm/llvm-project/llvmorg-10.0.1/llvm/examples/Kaleidoscope/include/KaleidoscopeJIT.h